# Cannot parse the following text file into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, awk, dataframe

I have the following text file `file1.txt` in this format (showing it exactly as I see it):

```
 3612  11.4 21.5  1.3  cat3        10469   11447 9239174 -  Smith      David       
  484  25.1 13.2  0.0  cat3        11505   11675 9238946 -  John       Mary        
  239  29.4  1.9  1.0  cat3        11678   11780 9238841 +  Weiz       Parker
  318  23.0  3.7  0.0  cat3        15265   15355 9235266 +  Cohen      Charles
   18  23.2  0.0  2.0  cat3        15798   15849 9234772 +  Lopez      Beth        
  463   1.3  0.6  1.7  cat3        10001   10468 9240153 +  Brown      Charlie
```

I wanted to immediately load this into a Pandas DataFrame with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame("file1.txt")
```

But this gives me a dataframe with only one column.

So, I tried to parse this file into a `.csv` with Python. The problem is that this isn't a "constant" delimiter, i.e. it's not a tab.

```
import csv
input_text = csv.reader(open("file1.txt", "r"), delimiter = "\t")
output_csv =  csv.writer(open("file1.csv", 'w'))
output_csv.writerows(input_text)  # this should write a csv "file1.csv"
```

However, this gives the same results. The delimiter `delimiter = ""` also doesn't work.

How can I parse this text file into csv format? Can I do this with Python? (or do I need awk?) Should I be "skipping" the intermediary csv step and try to do this entirely in pandas?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: use `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: @HYRY Doesn't seem to work---results in a dataframe of only one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pd.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with a separator and specify the column names and also specify that there are no column headers already included in the csv file.

```
In [24]: pd.read_csv("file1.txt", header=None, names=[chr(i) for i in range(65, 75)], sep="\s+")
Out[24]: 
         A     B    C     D      E      F        G  H      I        J
3612  11.4  21.5  1.3  cat3  10469  11447  9239174  -  Smith    David
484   25.1  13.2  0.0  cat3  11505  11675  9238946  -   John     Mary
239   29.4   1.9  1.0  cat3  11678  11780  9238841  +   Weiz   Parker
318   23.0   3.7  0.0  cat3  15265  15355  9235266  +  Cohen  Charles
18    23.2   0.0  2.0  cat3  15798  15849  9234772  +  Lopez     Beth
463    1.3   0.6  1.7  cat3  10001  10468  9240153  +  Brown  Charlie
```